# `CAGradientLayer` Define Start and End Points in Terms of Local Coordinate Space

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, cagradientlayer

A `CAGradientLayer` has two properties `startPoint` and `endPoint`. These properties are defined in terms of the unit coordinate space. The result is that if I have two gradient layers with the same start and end points each with different bounds, the two gradients will be different.

How can the `startPoint` and `endPoint` of a `CAGradientLayer` layer be defined not in terms of the unit coordinate space but in standard point coordinates so that the angle/size of the gradient is not affected by the bounds of the layer?

The desired result is that a gradient layer can be resized to any size or shape and the gradient remain in place, although cropped differently.

---

Qualifications:
I know that this seems like an absolutely trivial transformation between coordinate spaces, but apparently either, yes I am in fact that dumb, or perhaps there's something either broken or extremely counter-intuitive about how `CAGradientLayer`s work. I haven't included an example of what I expect should be the right way to do it, because (assuming I'm just dumb) it would only be misleading.

---

**Edit:**

Here is the implementation I have of a `CALayer` which adds a sub `CAGradientLayer` and configures it's start and end points. It does not produce the desired results.

```
@interface MyLayer ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer;
@end

@implementation MyLayer

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer new];
        [self addSublayer:self.gradientLayer];
        self.gradientLayer.colors = @[ (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,  (id)[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];;
        self.gradientLayer.locations = @[ @0, @.333, @.666, @1 ];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSublayers {
    [super layoutSublayers];
    self.gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    self.gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    self.gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(100 / self.bounds.size.width, 40 / self.bounds.size.height);
}

@end
```

I have a .xib file with a number of `MyLayer`'s of different sizes. The gradients of the layers are all different.

Comment: What was the outcome on this?

Answer (score 1):

> How can the startPoint and endPoint of a CAGradientLayer layer be defined not in terms of the unit coordinate space but in standard point coordinates so that the angle/size of the gradient is not effected by the bounds of the layer?

It can't. But you can easily think of a different strategy. For example:

- Paint the gradient a different way (using Quartz instead relying on a CAGradientLayer to paint it for you).
- Use a mask so that the layer *appears* to be a certain size and shape, and you can change that size and shape by changing the mask, but actually the layer itself is one big constantly sized layer with the same gradient all the time.
- Detect that the gradient layer has changed bounds, and change the gradient `startPoint` and `endPoint` to match. Here's a working example of a view whose layer is a gradient layer and does this - but you have to remember to redraw the layer every time the bounds change!

  ```
  override func drawLayer(layer: CALayer!, inContext ctx: CGContext!) {
      let grad = layer as! CAGradientLayer
      grad.colors = [UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor, UIColor.redColor().CGColor]
      let maxx:CGFloat = 500.0 // or whatever
      let maxy:CGFloat = 500.0 // or whatever
      grad.startPoint = CGPointMake(0,0) // or whatever!
      grad.endPoint = CGPointMake(maxx/self.bounds.width, maxy/self.bounds.height)
  }
  ```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your first option matches my attempted implementation almost exactly, but the gradients on different layers are all different. Is this code behaving correctly for you?

Comment: Depends what "correctly" means. I am not changing the `startPoint` but obviously I could do that too! And so could you. Thus, for example, we could make the virtual start point be the top left of the superview if desired.

Comment: Of course, other details could be implement. But you do see the end point at (500, 500) regardless of the size of the layer? In my own test project, I have a number of different size/shape layers which implement something like this and the size of the layer is, inscrutably, effecting the gradients.

Comment: Yes, the end point is off the screen down at the left, where 500,500 would be, no matter how big the view is. Wait, I will add pix.

Comment: There you go. As you can see, the larger view size "reveals" more of the "underlying" gradient, but the upper left corner of both views is the same - the gradient itself is constant.

Comment: Yup. That looks exactly right. I included my sample code (sorry for my archaic parlance) do you see any obvious difference?

Comment: The thing is, I have no idea what else you are doing. You say you have a xib with layers of different sizes, but that cannot be true; you can't put a layer in a xib. So I don't really know what you mean. Would you like to post your example project on github or somewhere that I can get at it? I'll be glad to take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77116/discussion-between-anthony-mattox-and-matt).

Answer (score 1):

You can't define the startPoint and endPoint otherwise.  You have two options:

- Calculate those based on the view height (50 pixels for a 100 pixels view height = 0.5, for a 100 pixels view height = 0.25)
- Create a gradient at the largest fixed size required (ex: with a height of 568), and add it as a subview of another view that will be resized for your needs, with clipsToBounds enabled.  That way, you could achieve what you want (have the gradient always start at the top and clip the bottom, keep the gradient centered and clip the top and the bottom, etc)

Comment: Yes. As you point out, that feature is not directly available on a Gradient Layer, but creating a wrapper or a subclass and performing the transformations you mention would be just as good. The problem is, getting those transformations to work as you describe proved more difficult than I expected.

Comment: Using  a larger clipped gradient would also work, but your first strategy seems like the right one. It appears more efficient and scalable.

Comment: The second strategy has an advantage in that you are assured to be using the same gradient.  The first is more "lightweight" and simple, but computing ratio can bring disparencies caused by rounding.

Comment: I hadn't considered, discrepancies in the rendering. That's an interesting possibility that could be an issue if the layers are... layered. That aside, are you able to get a working implementation of the first solution? I'm getting bizarre results trying to implement it.